# How many Connections from Device to FCM will be made If the Device has Two Android APPs which points to same Firebase Project

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

One Firebase Project has Two Android Apps in one Device. Will the device make Single Connection to FCM or will the Device make Two Connections to FCM from the DEVICE (for each APP)

Answer (score 1):

Got the response from FCM Support:

> Q1: I've Two Apps in one FCM Project, when Both of these apps gets installed on to the same device, Will it generate Two Separate FCM Registration Tokens Even Though both the apps resides in the same Device?
>
> A1: Registration tokens are generated per app instance. Even if they have the same project it should generate two different registration tokens.
>
> Q2: How many Network Connections from Android Device to FCM will be made If the Device has Two Android apps which points to same Firebase Project.
>
> A2: There's always only one connection with FCM service through Google play services. The device syncs with FCM servers and maintain it regardless of the number of apps connecting to FCM.